# Get the mean value for range of dates from a time series and based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` contains three columns: `Agent` and a datetime range (`start` and `end`).
`df2` contains timeseries with three columns: `Agent`, `datetime` and `value`.

I would like to calculate the `mean` value and `count` the numbers of values within the range for every `Agent` and `datetime range` in `df1` from the second file `df2` entries and add this to the first file.

**df1:**

| index | Agent | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| 0 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 14:10:00 | 2022-08-18 15:20:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-08-18 14:00:00 | 2022-08-18 16:05:00 |
| 2 | Max | 2022-08-18 14:25:00 | 2022-08-18 15:00:00 |
| 3 | Sam | 2022-08-18 16:12:00 | 2022-08-18 16:20:00 |

**df2:**

| index | Agent | datetime_log | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 14:00:14 | 246 |
| 1 | John | 2022-08-18 14:00:14 | 33 |
| 2 | Max | 2022-08-18 14:00:14 | 1080 |
| 3 | Sam | 2022-08-18 14:00:14 | 500 |
| 4 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 14:30:14 | 367 |
| 5 | John | 2022-08-18 14:30:14 | 50 |
| 6 | Max | 2022-08-18 14:30:14 | 970 |
| 7 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 15:00:14 | 290 |
| 8 | John | 2022-08-18 15:00:14 | 75 |
| 9 | Max | 2022-08-18 15:00:14 | 800 |
| 10 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 15:30:14 | 244 |
| 11 | John | 2022-08-18 15:30:14 | 120 |
| 12 | Max | 2022-08-18 15:30:14 | 1800 |

what I want is (desired output):

| index | Agent | start_date | end_date | mean_df2 | count_df2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0 | Andrew | 2022-08-18 14:10:00 | 2022-08-18 15:20:00 | 328.5 | 2 |
| 1 | John | 2022-08-18 14:00:00 | 2022-08-18 16:05:00 | 69.5 | 4 |
| 2 | Max | 2022-08-18 14:25:00 | 2022-08-18 15:00:00 | 970 | 1 |
| 3 | Sam | 2022-08-18 16:12:00 | 2022-08-18 16:20:00 |  | 0 |

My problem is the condition.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should use `groupby()`

Comment: what did you try? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start_date'])
df1['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end_date'])
df2['datetime_log'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime_log'])

df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on = 'Agent', how = 'left')


df['flag'] = np.where(((df['start_date'] <= df['datetime_log']) & (df['datetime_log']< df['end_date'])), 1, 0)
df = df[df['flag'] == 1]
df_final = df.groupby('Agent').agg({'value':['mean', 'count']})
print(df_final)

value      
         mean count
Agent              
Andrew  328.5     2
John     69.5     4
Max     970.0     1
```